# multiple elements with similar css

Tags: css

I have multiple html elements. They use very similar css styles. Only difference is border style (one element has all but left border, another all but right etc).

So far, i used to create several different styles which have only one line of code different. That seriously bloated my css file. Is there any better solution to my problem? Is there any kind of inheritance that i could use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is many ways to achieve that.

1. Use multiple selectors:

   ```
   selector #1, selector #2, selector #3 {
       /* common styles */
   }
   selector #1 { border-left: none; }
   selector #2 { border-right: none; }
   selector #3 { border-top: none; }
   ```
2. Depending on document structure you can try something like this:

   ```
   <ul>
      <li>Element #1</li>
      <li>Element #2</li>
      <li>Element #3</li>
   </ul>


   ul li {
       /* common styles */
   }
   ul li:first-child { border-left: none; }
   ul li:last-child { border-right: none; }
   ```
3. Use multiple classes:

   ```
   <ul>
      <li class="border no-left">Element #1</li>
      <li class="border">Element #2</li>
      <li class="border no-right">Element #3</li>
   </ul>


   .border {
       /* common styles */
   }
   .border.no-left { border-left: none; }
   .border.no-right { border-right: none; }
   ```

Comment: Nice one, thank you! But what when i have something like this: input[type=button]:hover similar to something like this: input[type=button] ???

Comment: @johan That's the first case in the answer above: use commas to separate multiple, arbitrarily-complex selectors and assign them to the same style. Note that I believe that [this is only appropriate when there is a semantic relationship](http://phrogz.net/CSS/HowToDevelopWithCSS.html#groupstyles) between the selected elements. _(Or if you are **desperate** to save a few bytes.)_

Comment: `:hover` pseudoclass can be interpreted as " **extra** styles for indicated element", so `input[type=button] { common-styles } input[type=button]:hover { specific-styles }`

Comment: -1 there are errors in the code, also if someone is asking this question, best to not introduce pseudo-elements to a noob :\ Also, I've seen inconsistent results with double-class CSS .x.y

Comment: What errors? I didn't tested that code, but at a glance I can't find any. "pseudo-elements"... you mean "xxx:xxx-child"? What's wrong about them? `.x.y` selector is well supported. Only old and **dead** IE6 had some troubles in some *specific* cases with that.

Comment: and yes, while IE6 is mostly dead, it still represents 30% of users in non-tech service industries :\

Comment: @Kirk: I've fixed these dots.

Answer (score 4):

You can declare an element with several classes

```
<div class="general-class left-border-class"></div>
<div class="general-class top-border-class"></div>
...
```

Answer (score 3):

CSS

```
.border {
    border: solid #555 2px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    }
    .border.left {
        border-width: 0 2px 0 0;
        }
    .border.right {
        border-width: 0 0 0 2px;
        }
```

HTML

```
<div class="border left"></div>
<div class="border"></div>
<div class="border right"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this particular scenario - where you have elements with different border styles - you can use the `:first-child` pseudo-class.

***Live demo:*** http://jsfiddle.net/7WJe9/1/